# SQL Server: Get the last row entries (more than one) with sql query

Tags: sql-server, excel, t-sql, gridview

**Scenario**: a user will copy and paste data (multiple rows) from an Excel sheet onto my webpage and press submit. When this occurs, the data will be saved into a SQL Server table. The current date will also be saved next to each row.

Now, in another gridview, I would like to view only these multiple rows that have been pasted /saved to DB that certain day.

So I was thinking about using TOP / MAX(date) but Top returns specified rows only, and MAX only 1 row.

Anyone out there that has done this before or can help get a working query?

Comment: A sample data would help and what have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried TOP and MAX. I am asking for suggestions??

Comment: I think your best approach would be passing the max date and getting the top 1 desc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `TOP WITH TIES` in order to get all last entries:

```
SELECT TOP(1) WITH TIES
...
ORDER BY submit_date DESC;
```

Comment: Based off this I tried:       select * FROM table
where DateSaved IN (SELECT MAX(DateSaved) FROM table)
select top(1) with ties * FROM table
order by DateSaved desc - but still only return one row

Comment: Then there is no tie. Maybe a time part in `DateSaved`? Try `ORDER BY CAST(DateSaved AS DATE) DESC`.

Comment: Thank you. It works. Forgot about the second value sql records.

Answer (score 0):

Is "that certain day" based on a specific day or a 24 hour interval?

You can make the gridview query the data where the date field is higher than or equal to dateadd(dd, -1, getdate())

Or if you mean the current day as in the current date, where the date is equal to the date of getdate.

Comment: Say for ex the user saved the data on date 15 May 2017. I want to display only 15 May 2017. The problem is, I cannot use  "dateadd(dd, -1, getdate())" this because sometimes days/ or a week go past so you cannot accurately determine the date that way.